# How to find Array length inside the Handlebar templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars template which is rendered using a json object. In this json I am sending an array. Like this:

```
var json = {
               "array":["abc","def","ghi","jkl"] 
}
```

Now in my template I want to find the length of this array. Something like:

```
{{#each item}}
   {{ array.length }}
{{/each}}
```

Couldn't find it in the Handlebars documentation.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

My Bad....

`{{array.length}}` actually worked inside the template. Should have checked/tested it before posting it here.

Comment: well, you saved me from having to test it out, so thanks.  :)

Comment: This doesn't work at least for Mandrills flavor of handlebars for anyone that is wondering.  I have not yet found a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 51):

In this case you need to reference the parent variable of the each from within the each block:

```
{{#each array}}
    {{../array.length}}
{{/each}}
```

I think your variable being named "array" is probably conflating the issue as well. Let's assume some different JSON just to clarify:

```
var json = {
    "fruit":["apple","orange","banana"]
};
```

So then doing this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each fruit}}
        <li>{{this}} {{@index}} {{../fruit.length}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Would yield:

```
<ul>
    <li>apple 0 3</li>
    <li>orange 1 3</li>
    <li>banana 2 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the list items would be `apple 0 3` `orange 1 3` `banana 2 3`

Comment: @Paul, you're correct, example updated to reflect the correct output.

Comment: Related question: how do you get the length of an array when it's the current pipeline value?

Comment: Syntactically, this answer makes more sense than the accepted answer.

Comment: This was a great answer and should be chosen as the correct one!

Answer (score 3):

You can define simple helper to handle it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('get_length', function (obj) {
 return obj.length;
});
```

And then use it in your template eg:

```
{{get_length some_object}}
```

Comment: `length` is a property of the object, it's not necessary to register helpers to get the value of a property since Handlebars supports dot notation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing for an empty list in order to display content...
In Ember.js which uses handlebars, you can have an else for the #each.

```
{{#each blah as |blah|}}

{{else}}
 //   If array is empty
{{/each}}
```