# Handlebars get last item index

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Using [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) to generate a css3 slideshow.

template:

```
{{#slider}}
    <ul>
    {{#each images}}
    <li><img src="{{url}}"" alt="{{caption}}" /></li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>

    {{#if infinity}}
    <label class="goto-first" for="slides_1"></label>

    {{#foreach images}}
    <label class="goto-last" for="slides_{{#if @last}}{{@index}}{{/if}}"></label>
    {{/each}}

    {/if}}
{{/slider}}
```

Let's say I have 4 images, first is ok, I don't touch it and last needs to returns this `label.goto-last[for="slides_4]`

Tried with `foreach` but I am gatting erros.

`infinity` is a slider option `false`/`true`.

Any ideeas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with a json 'array', if the current index is equal to the array length then it will be the last item.

[How to find Array length inside the Handlebar templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428584/how-to-find-array-length-inside-the-handlebar-templates)

Comment: thanks. yes I am using json array and `images.length` this did the trick

Comment: actually there is a problem here.. for 3 images I have @index returning 0,1,2 and images.length returns 3. How can I get 2 instead of 3? like length-1

Comment: found a solution, using {{last images}} with Handlebars.registerHelper("last", function(array) {return array.length-1;});